# Is there a hover Event for a table row in a TableViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

i have a JFace table-viewer, which consists of large number of rows, i thought that it would be better if there is a short description for each row,as a workaround i was trying to implement doubleclick listner but that's not apt to my need,i don't know if there is an event like hover for this,which shows a tooltip containing a brief info about the particular row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question depends somewhat on the exact implementation of your table viewer. Having said that, the primary options are:

- Add a `MouseTrackListener` to the underlying table
- Add a SWT `Listener` for `SWT.MouseHover` to the underlying table
- If you use a `CellLabelProvider`, have a look at the various `getToolTip...(Object)` methods

For the first two, you have to figure out the row element yourself - look at `event.item.getData()`, whereas that is provide to you in the last option...

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets - here you can find plenty of examples.